# Initial object movement lag in applications while holding down arrow keys

Tags: algorithm, windows, anti-patterns

In Windows applications, when a 'movement' is associated with a key ,namely scrolling down a web page by holding down (constantly, without releasing) the arrow keys or moving the objects in a game by doing so), the movement is performed like this: first a sudden and jerky movement takes place and then after a short instance the movement continues. However, in 'Role player games' this cannot be seen and we experience a smooth movement. What is the cause of this type of movement and how can it be solved while writing a Windows application? (Note that this is seen to be regardless of programming language.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not an anti-pattern. It's intentional feature: for most of the time, you need to input a single character. Only after a delay, auto-repeat kicks in, because by holding the key you have clearly expressed that you need pretty many repeats. As you need pretty many, the repeat interval is smaller than delay after a single character.

The same behavior is extended onto the cursor keys.

If there were no delay after first cursor movement, most users would have hard time moving it by 1 letter. If you need to move exactly by 3 letters, you can get a precise result by triple-pressing.

You can control the delay and repeat speed in your Control Panel's keyboard settings.

In a specific application, normally, you subscribe to `KeyDown`/`KeyUp` events and handle the repeat functionality yourself. In games, you just check if a specific cursor key is down, and get equal movement on every cycle of the main loop.